# Android Camera2 MediaRecorder crop video during recording

Tags: java, android, video, aspect-ratio, android-mediarecorder

I have requirements to build a camera app that records in a 16:9 ratio that matches the full height of the recording device in 1280x720, android MediaRecorder only returns very specific dimensions per device that can be supported during recording and with most devices 1280x720 is available and works as intended, however for some devices such as the Galaxy S4 the recorded video returns stretched and disfigured, the reason being that the Galaxy s4 dimensions are 1920x1080.

Now the android Camera2 google example shoots in a 4:3 aspect ratio and this produces the right aspect ratio for video quality but not the intended size that I am after, from my research it appears my only option would be to record in 4:3 and perform some sort of a crop on the video so it will be closer to the 16:9 1280x720 range, is there a way that this can be done with the MediaRecorder or alternative framework?